# AngularJS - I have a different behavior when creating the carousel items with ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, owl-carousel

I have a template that allows me to create items inside a panel with a background image and some text. Something super simple.

The initial code would be this:

```
<div class="container-fluid p-0 pb-5">
    <div class="owl-carousel header-carousel position-relative mb-5">


        <!-- <div class="owl-carousel-item position-relative">
            <img class="img-fluid" src="img/carousel-1.jpg" alt="">
            <div class="position-absolute top-0 start-0 w-100 h-100 d-flex align-items-center"
                style="background: rgba(6, 3, 21, .5);">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row justify-content-start">
                        <div class="col-10 col-lg-8">
                            <h1 class="display-3 text-white animated slideInDown mb-4">hola</h1>
                            <p class="fs-5 fw-medium text-white mb-4 pb-2">paraffito</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="owl-carousel-item position-relative">
            <img class="img-fluid" src="img/carousel-2.jpg" alt="">
            <div class="position-absolute top-0 start-0 w-100 h-100 d-flex align-items-center"
                style="background: rgba(6, 3, 21, .5);">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row justify-content-start">
                        <div class="col-10 col-lg-8">
                            <h1 class="display-3 text-white animated slideInDown mb-4">hola 2</h1>
                            <p class="fs-5 fw-medium text-white mb-4 pb-2">paraffito 2</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div> 
    </div>
</div>
```

This works perfectly, however when I transform this HTML so that the items are created based on an array that I have the behavior is different, and for some reason instead of being a single carousel, it is as if I were stacking multiple carousels with a single items in each.
This would be my HTML transformed with ng-repeat:

```
    <div class="container-fluid p-0 pb-5">
    <div class="owl-carousel header-carousel position-relative mb-5">

            <div ng-repeat="objetosConImagenes in objetosConImagenes" class="owl-carousel-item position-relative" >
            <img class="img-fluid" ng-src="{{objetosConImagenes.imagenUrl}}" alt="">
            <div class="position-absolute top-0 start-0 w-100 h-100 d-flex align-items-center"
                style="background: rgba(6, 3, 21, .5);">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row justify-content-start">
                        <div class="col-10 col-lg-8">
                            <h1 class="display-3 text-white animated slideInDown mb-4">
                                {{objetosConImagenes.TituloPresentacion}}</h1>
                            <p class="fs-5 fw-medium text-white mb-4 pb-2">{{objetosConImagenes.DescCorta}}</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


    </div>
</div>
```

I don't know if it has something to do with the problem, but I have these libraries in use.

```
    <!-- JavaScript Libraries -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.8.2/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/parametros.js"></script>
<script src="js/scriptv2.js"></script>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="lib/wow/wow.min.js"></script>
<!-- <script src="lib/easing/easing.min.js"></script>
<script src="lib/waypoints/waypoints.min.js"></script>-->
<script src="lib/counterup/counterup.min.js"></script>
<script src="lib/owlcarousel/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>

<!-- Template Javascript -->
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
```

What am I doing wrong? What can I do to achieve the same behavior as in the original HTML?
I know there is a Bootstrap UI for AngularJS, however I would love to keep this project simple and have it work this way.